# PHP docs question

Tags: php

Where can I find the PHP docs for PHP version 1,2 and 3?

Comment: Please be aware that PHP versions 4 and lower are *entirely unsupported* and reached end of life years ago.  **These ancient versions of PHP should not be used in production.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- [PHP 2](http://www.php.net/manual/phpfi2.php)
- [PHP 3](http://www.php.net/manual/php3.php)

Comment: where do they explain about the functions available in each version and the changes made to it?

Comment: @oneall: Since there were drastic changes between each version, I doubt there would be a changelog listing each function. The current documentation (PHP 4 <=) does, however, have such a log.

Answer (score 1):

[PHP/FI 2.0 Manual](http://www.php.net/manual/phpfi2.php)

[PHP 3 Manual](http://www.php.net/manual/php3.php)

(as linked [here](http://php.net/docs.php))

Comment: where do they explain about the functions available in each version and the changes made to it?

Answer (score 0):

The PHP v3 manual is archived at http://www.php.net/manual/php3.php

I'm not aware that there ever was a single PHP manual for v1 or v2.

**Update:** Tim found it!

Comment: where do they explain about the functions available in each version and the changes made to it?